# How to disable a button after user clicks on it in Racket?

Tags: user-interface, button, racket

I'm having trouble figuring out how to disable a button after the user clicks on it in Racket.

Here is some sample code with explanation on what im doing:

Make a frame by instantiating the frame% class

```
(define frame (new frame% [label "Example"]))
```

Make a static text message in the frame

```
(define msg (new message% [parent frame]
                          [label "No events so far..."]))
```

Make a button in the frame

```
(new button% [parent frame]
     [label "Click Me"]
     ; Callback procedure for a button click:
     [callback (lambda (button event)
                 (send msg set-label "Button click")
                 )])
```

Show the frame by calling its show method

```
(send frame show #t)
```

I also understand that  `[enabled #f]` will disable the button if I put it in the field but it disables the button before i even click on it and I want it to disable the button after I click on the button. I think the trick lies within the callback because the callback occurs when the button is clicked but I don't know how to fix this issue. Code would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following [method](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/window___.html?q=enabled#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._mred%2Fmain..rkt%29._window~3c~25~3e%29._enable%29%29) to disable a window:

```
(send a-window enable enable?)
```

So, in your case, callback becomes:

```
(send button enable #f)
```

For example, modifying new button to:

```
(new button% [parent frame]
             [label "Click Me"]
             [callback (lambda (button event)
                         (send msg set-label "Button click")
                         (send button enable #f))])
```

would disable the button upon user clicking.